# Best way to dynamically monitor SQL column value in view?

Tags: sql

I have a database that has been partitioned into various yyyymmdd aggregated views.  There's a column in each of those partitioned views called speed.  Is there a way to actively monitor the speed value in the partition view, compared with the previous day's max value and insert into another table if today's speed value is greater than yesterday?

Comment: What database, can you provide example data and expected output?

Comment: Your only tool to do this kind of thing (from within the database) is triggers. Triggers are very platform dependent, so that will have an effect on what your options are. You may also want to consider whether you don't want to rather have an efficient query to extract your desired result set from source data on demand. Using triggers to add derived data to another table is duplication, and you'll have to maintain that data based on changes to the source tables - this tends to be error prone.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a general solution across all database platforms which use SQL, then the answer is no, at least not in the database.

However, most databases have a trigger mechanism.  Whether or not they support views depends on the database that you are using.  SQL Server, for example, [does allow triggers on views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254(SQL.80).aspx).

If you are willing to use a database-specific solution, then this is the direction I would recommend looking down first.

For a general solution across all databases, you would have to rely on application code, polling the value on a regular basis and then comparing it against your condition before you take your action.